# recursion function that checks if the string contains certain char

Tags: c, string

Hi I need to write down a code that usses recursion that gets string and char and returns -1 if the string doesnt contain the char and the place of the char if it contains it.

this is my code:

```
int str_contains(char* string, char ch)
{
     if(*string==ch) return 0;
     if(*string=='\0') return -1;
     int check =str_contains(string+1,ch)+1;
     if(check==-1) return -1;
     return check;
}
```

the code doesnt work and returns number even if I enter a string that doesnt contain the char.

Comment: `int check = (-1) + 1;` if `str_contains(string+1,ch)` return `-1`.

Comment: try `int check =str_contains(string+1,ch);
     if(check==-1) return -1;
     return check+1;`

Comment: So what did you do except asking for help? Did you for example go mentally or with pen and paper through the steps of str_contains ("a", 'b') or str_contains ("ab", 'c')?

Answer (score 1):

this part does not make sense

```
if(check==-1) return -1;
return check;
```

Try this function, if you reached the end of the string, check value will be equal to 0 because check = -1 +1.

```
int str_contains(char* string, char ch) {
    if(*string == ch) 
        return 0;
    if(*string == '\0') 
        return -1;
    int check = str_contains(string+1, ch) + 1;
    return check > 0? check:-1;
}
```

If check is greater than 0 it means that you have found an occurence of the char so you'll return check value, if it's less or equal to zero you reached the termination character and you'll return -1.

Comment: i tried your code and its not working, if I enter '12345' the function returns -1

Comment: It works for me, iI tried it with string "12345" and all characters '1', '2', '3', '4' and '5' and returns the right index.

You have to call like this `str_contains("12345", '2');`

Answer (score 1):

this function does what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int str_contains(char* string, char ch, int index)
{

     if( *(string + index) == ch)
        return index;

     if ( *(string + index) == '\0' )
      return -1;

     return str_contains(string, ch, index+1);
}

int main() {
  char * str = "hello";
  printf("Position of o in hello is %d", str_contains(str, '\0', 0 ));
}
```

You are making various errors in your approach. First of all you need to identify the base case of your recursion algorithm. The base case are those condition which will stop the recursion. In your case there are two base cases:

1. you reach the end of the string.
2. you find the characters you were looking for.

if none of the previous conditions is met, then we can increase the index and call again the same function on the remainder of the string.

Comment: OP version can find '\0'.  your's not.

Comment: why would you search for `\0`?

Comment: For example, `strchr` can look for `'\0'`.
It is considered to be the version is not a pointer.

Comment: fair enough. I can update my answer to take into account that

Comment: @BLUEPIXY no it is not. it does it one time

Comment: @BLUEPIXY updated my answer and it addresses both your points

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply that way :

```
int str_contains(char* string, char ch)
{
     if(*string==ch) return 0;
     if(*string=='\0') return -1;
     int check =str_contains(string+1,ch); // keep return value unchanged to test -1
     return (check==-1) ? -1 : check + 1;
}
```